# Pagination Sorting with jQueryDataTables rerender problem

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, rerender

I found the javaScript jQueryDataTables for pagination and sorting. I add the code and the javaScript to my org and visualforce page.
If I open the page for the first time, the script works fine, but If I rerender the pageblock the function from the jQueryDataTables disappear.

I read something about the actionFunction, but I don't know how can I use this in my code.

Could you help me with this issue, please.

```
<apex:pageblock title="Accounts ({!TotalRecs})" id="pbAcc" rendered="{!IF(AccList2.size != NULL,true,false)}">
    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!AccList2}" var="Acc">        
        <apex:column headervalue="LINK" style="background-color:{!IF(Acc.Id=SelectedAccountId,"#7394ce","")}">
            <apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="/{!Acc.Id}">Details</apex:outputLink>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!getOppList}" rerender="pbAcc, pbOpp, oppAccDL, oppAccDR, oppOppList, pbAccDL, pbAccDR, pbOppD, pbPlanB, oppPlanBWS, pbPlanE, oppPlanE">
                <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedAccountId}" value="{!Acc.Id}" name="SelectedAccountId"/>                  
                <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedUserId2}" value="{!Acc.OwnerId}" name="SelectedUserId2"/>                    
            </apex:actionSupport>    
        </apex:column>    
        <apex:column headervalue="Account Name" style="background-color:{!IF(Acc.Id=SelectedAccountId,"#7394ce","")}">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Acc.Name}" />
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!getOppList}" rerender="pbAcc, pbOpp, oppAccDL, oppAccDR, oppOppList, pbAccDL, pbAccDR, pbOppD, pbPlanB, oppPlanB, pbPlanE, oppPlanE">
                <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedAccountId}" value="{!Acc.Id}" name="SelectedAccountId"/>     
                <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedUserId2}" value="{!Acc.OwnerId}" name="SelectedUserId2"/>                                    
            </apex:actionSupport>
        </apex:column>                  
         <apex:column headervalue="Berater" style="background-color:{!IF(Acc.Id=SelectedAccountId,"#7394ce","")}">             
            <apex:outputField value="{!Acc.Owner.Name}"/>                              
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!getOppList}" rerender="pbAcc, pbOpp, oppAccDL, oppAccDR, oppOppList, pbAccDL, pbAccDR, pbOppD, pbPlanB, oppPlanB, pbPlanE, oppPlanE">
                <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedAccountId}" value="{!Acc.Id}" name="SelectedAccountId"/>                  
                <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedUserId2}" value="{!Acc.OwnerId}" name="SelectedUserId2"/>                    
            </apex:actionSupport>
        </apex:column>                      
    </apex:pageblocktable>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryDataTables, 'js/jquery.js')}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryDataTables, 'js/jquery.dataTables.js')}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$('table.dataTable').dataTable({
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
});
</script>
```

Thanks,
peX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you re-render the part of the page that contains the table, then you also have to re-register the JavaScript logic.

You can do this via the `oncomplete` attribute:

```
<apex:actionSupport oncomplete="addDataTable()" event="onclick" .../>
```

with the JavaScript moved into a function:

```
<script>
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
function addDataTable() {
    j$('table.dataTable').dataTable({
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    });
}
// Add when page loads
addDataTable();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using StandardSetController for pagination. It has next() method which returns next set of records.
[StandardSetController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm)